# laravel schedule protection from sending bulk email multiple times

Tags: php, laravel

I use mailchimp to send bulk emails once per day.
I use the laravel scheduler to execute the API calls to Mailchimp.

Do I need to protect myself from accidentally executing the scheduled calls multiple times? (i.e. could the scheduled job potentially run multiple times when laravel crashes?)

Comment: Why? Why isn't this a scheduled campaign in MailChimp? Could you use the MailChimp api to create a campaign perhaps?

Comment: I generate the campaign on the fly since the content is different every time and I compose the mail html from DB content

Comment: Well, the scheduler would only run when you set it to run.  Without seeing your code or the schedule, this question is pretty broad.

Answer (score 0):

its best practice to protect yourself even if it won't happen , you can add tracking for that schedule, like adding it to the database with the time of the execution and the time of the end of the execution. "Better safe then sorry" because probably you will some subscribers or marked as spam if that happen.

PS : the finish time is just to check if the task finished executing.